# What bracha do you make on zucchini flowers or the curly "lettuce" used for garnish?

Tags: halacha, blessing, eating, vegetables

During the past few years I have seen caterers decorate platters with zucchini flowers. Similarly. many platters have some type of dark green or purple lettuce or cabbage (I'm not sure what kind of veggie this is) under the food.

Usually, these things are not eaten raw, but, I guess zuccini flowers in particular are becoming more of a common edible item now than it was about 5-10 years ago. Would the bracha on these 2 be "admah" or still "shehakol" because it's not yet customary to eat thse raw?

Comment: Questions like this must be decided by a local rav, but there is almost certainly room to do it either way.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37936

Comment: Best policy would be to make a brachah on something there is no doubt about with intention to include the doubtful items, or shehakol because that's the catch-all brachah.

Comment: @Epicentre - This is a known answer, and a common answer regarding similar brachot conundrums. The most common is to eat bread and say Hamotzi and include the zucchini flowers as part of the meal. It works, but, it misses the focus of my question. Some people, such as I, like to eat things so that we can make a bracha, not make a bracha so that we can eat something. Hence, the reason for my question. We like to have the benefit of the specific bracha for the food we are eating, rather than using a work-around.